# Table inside jQuery does not work, but outside does

Tags: jquery, html-table

Table in the query does not work. When using a table outside no problem in the code.

JavaScript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.user').each(function(){
        var parent = this,
            group = $('.group', parent);
        $('.selectMe', parent).on('change', function(){
            var indis = $(':selected', this).index();
            if ( indis > 0 ){
                indis -= 1;
                group.hide().filter(':eq(' + indis + ')').fadeIn(300);
            } else {
                group.hide();
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

HTML

```
<style>
  .group {
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd
  }

</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>

      <div class="user">
        <select class="selectMe">
          <option value="">select</option>
          <option value="1">one</option>
          <option value="2">two</option>
        </select>

    </td>


    <td>

      <div class="group">
        one
      </div>

      <div class="group">
        two
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I know exactly where I'm making a mistake. How to use jQuery in table I need to make an arrangement

Comment: Proper formatting (indentation) tends to make this type of problem obvious. Use any of the free editors that do that for you on the fly.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, as Paul says it's shorthand for `$(this).parent().find('.selectMe')`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unfinished `div.user` inside a table cell. You're trying to find `.selectMe`, etc. within that container - however that container doesn't have any of those items inside. They're inside other cells.

Consider moving the `user` class to the table itself, and removing the partial `<div>` tag, e.g.

```
<table class="user"> 
  <tr>
  <td>

    <select class="selectMe">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
    </select>
  </td>

  <td >

    <div  class="group" >
      one
    </div>

    <div class="group" >
      two
    </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```